# SQL XML Column filter based on XML node aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have XML column like below

```
<XMLDoc>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_A</Name>
      <Value>Val_A</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2001<dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_B</Name>
      <Value>Val_B</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2014<dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_C</Name>
      <Value>Val_C</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2012<dateReported>
    </AAA>
    <AAA>
      <Name>Name_D</Name>
      <Value>Val_D</Value>
      <dateReported>1/1/2011<dateReported>
    </AAA></x>
    <BB><ID>12</ID><BB>
    <CC><Type>XML</Type></CC>
</XMLDoc>
```

I need to fetch  name and value node for max of dateReported. So far my sQL is like below

```
SELECT 
   Col1 =  Col.value('(/XMLDoc/x/AAA/Name)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
   Col2 =  Col.value('(/XMLDoc/x/AAA/Value)[2]', 'varchar(255)'),
   Col3 = Col.value('(/XMLDoc/BB/ID)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),
   Col4 = Col.value('(/XMLDoc/CC/Type)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
FROM 
   table t
```

Basically I need my output to be `Name_B`, `Val_B`, `12`, `XML`, since `datereported` for AAA has max value.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but if you had used proper XML date strings in the format yyyy-MM-dd (i.e. 2014-12-24) you could have used the XQuery syntax for aggregate functions such as max: `select Col.query('max(for $d in /XMLDoc/AAA/dateReported return xs:date($d))') FROM[Table]`

Comment: Assuming date strings in proper format, can you give me modifeid SQL of my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this - setting up a CTE (Common Table Expression) to "extract" the XML values into a relational format, and then doing a simple `SELECT` on that result set:

```
;WITH XmlCTE AS 
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Name = XC.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        Value = XC.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        DateReported = XC.value('(dateReported)[1]', 'datetime')
        BB_ID = YourXmlColumn.value('(/XMLDoc/BB/ID)[1]', 'int'), 
        CC_Type = YourXmlColumn.value('(/XMLDoc/CC/Type)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
        dbo.YourTable 
    CROSS APPLY
        YourXmlColumn.nodes('/XMLDoc/AAA') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT *
FROM XmlCTE
WHERE DateReported = (SELECT MAX(DateReported) FROM XmlCTE)
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. But in my query i actually select from various other XML meaning different rows have different XMLs (XPath will be totally different), in that case how would i do crossapply.

Comment: @Saravanan: updated my response to include your `<BB><ID>` and `<CC>` elements

Answer (score 0):

Following [SQL XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/xml-in-sql-server-hierarchy-levels-cross-apply.aspx) can be used in this case

```
with cte as (
SELECT
    t.id,
    name.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as names,
    dates.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as dates
FROM t
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes('/XMLDoc/AAA') as XMLtable1(AAA)
CROSS APPLY XMLtable1.AAA.nodes('Name') as XMLtable2(name)
CROSS APPLY XMLtable1.AAA.nodes('dateReported') as XMLtable3(dates)
)
select * 
from (
select
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by dates desc)
from cte
) t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the updated requirement, following [SQL Server XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/query-sql-server-database-table-xml-data-using-cross-apply.aspx) can help
Please test the queries with more than one rows within the table for more accurate test results

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
    t.id,
    b.value('.','nvarchar(500)') as bbid,
    c.value('.','nvarchar(500)') as cc,
    name.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as names,
    dates.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as dates
FROM t
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes('/XMLDoc/BB/ID') as XMLtable4(b)
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes('/XMLDoc/CC') as XMLtable5(c)
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes('/XMLDoc/x') as XMLtable0(d)
CROSS APPLY XMLtable0.d.nodes('AAA') as XMLtable1(AAA)
CROSS APPLY XMLtable1.AAA.nodes('Name') as XMLtable2(name)
CROSS APPLY XMLtable1.AAA.nodes('dateReported') as XMLtable3(dates)
)
select * 
from (
select
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by dates desc)
from cte
) t where rn = 1
```